# Does STM provide fine-grained locking for existing data structures?

Tags: haskell, stm

Reading Bartosz Milewski's fantastic [blog post](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2010/09/11/beyond-locks-software-transactional-memory/) on STM, I was excited to read the following:

> But take into account an important fact: STM is very fine grained. For
>   instance, when you’re inserting an item into a tree, the STM
>   transaction will only lock the nodes that you are actually modifying.
>   STM will easily beat a solution that uses one global lock per whole
>   tree.

However, as I understand it, this behavior is not automatic, is it? If I use a `TVar (Map k a)`, will it not act as a single global lock on the whole map? And to gain the benefit of this fine-grained behavior, I (or someone) would have to implement a map replacement (`TMap`, for example) that contains `TVars` internally, correct?

This might seem like an obvious question, but reading up on STM implementation I was confused between reads of `TVar`s and reads of memory locations. I just want to make sure I have it right!

Bartosz goes further to say:

> Per-node manual locking is hard to implement correctly because
>   of the risk of deadlocks.

The difference with STM, as I understand it, is that while the STM implementation in effect uses locks the way a manually-locked solution might, the actual acquiry and release of locks is handled by the runtime, not the programmer - correct?

Comment: It depends on the implementation but there are many lock-free ways to implement STM (atomic compare and swap, for example).  As for your first question, yes you would need maps of `TVar`s and not a `TVar (Map k v)`.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson thanks for that. Do you mean that I can actually have a fine-grained `Map`, or would I need to completely re-implement `Map` to use `TVar`s internally?

Comment: Also, I just learned that 'acquiry' is actually a word. Lucky guess.

Comment: You can simply have a normal map with values that are `TVar`s.  More specifically, `Map k (TVar v)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `TVar` is a mutable cell. With immutable structures no two threads can transmit modifications back and forth, so we need some notion of mutable cell to cause the effect. In particular, we have

```
writeTVar :: TVar a -> a -> STM ()
```

which creates an `SMT` action replacing the value inside the mutable cell. We can sequence a few of these operations together, building a bigger and more complex `STM` action, and then call

```
atomically :: STM a -> IO a
```

to atomically commit the whole `STM` action at once. This is the "transactional" part of software transactional memory: other threads with their own references to these mutable cells will only ever witness the entirety of the `atomically`-performed `STM` action, no subparts. To achieve this Haskell might use locking, or something more clever—it's a mere implementation detail. The only thing `STM` asks you be cognizant of is that the actions within your `STM` block may be run repeatedly as necessary—and so side effects outside of modification of some shared memory cells are prohibited.

So how do we achieve fine-grained concurrency? Easily: we just provide more mutable cells for various threads to synchronize upon. For instance, we can read at least 3 different `Map` types.

```
TVar (Map k v)
Map k (TVar v)
TVar (Map k (TVar v))
```

The first will allow concurrent threads to make modifications to the entire `Map` all at once such that no partial changes are visible. The second, allows changes at any stored value, but maintains that the structure of the map itself—the choice of keys and the selection of stored values—is immutable and changes cannot be easily propagated to other threads.

The final choice, `TVar (Map k (TVar v))` is the most flexible. We can make wholesale modifications to the `Map` by synchronizing on the outer `TVar` and we can make changes to the values stored in the map by reading down to the value-`TVar`s and synchronizing on actions within them. The full set of possible semantics available for such a tree is myriad allowing both "whole `Map` locking" and "individual value locking" to happen together.

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thanks for the explanation. So just to be clear, even `TVar (Map k (TVar a))` does not achieve the fine-grained locking that Bartosz describes - that would require implementing a totally new `TMap` data structure which puts `TVars` around the internal nodes of the tree (if that is indeed the storage structure used), not just the leaves.

Comment: Yup, your granularity is exactly the same as the locations of your TVars.